# What is the underlying windowing system used in firefox OS?

Tags: operating-systems

I want to know the underlying windowing system used in firefox OS something equivalent to X for linux, surfaceflinger for android.

I searched the docs provided by the firefox community. But, I didn't get any clue.
Even I couldn't notice anything from the process list.

The documentation just provides the information that gaia layer uses the AppWindowFactory and other classes for managing the windows.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Firefox OS/Platform/Architecture](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox_OS/Platform/Architecture) on the MDN, as well as [this mailing list post](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.mozilla.devel.b2g/4588), the Gecko HTML renderer draws directly on the framebuffer using OpenGL.

> From: Andreas Gal
>
> [...] Our rendering engine (Gecko)
> acts as display server, and directly composites into the framebuffer
> using OpenGL ES. There is no benefit FFOS could derive from
> SurfaceFlinger or Wayland.